# How do I write a java code that will export a file to a usb drive

Tags: file, usb, transfer

It is exactly wnat the title says I have beenlooking for quite sometime and haven't found anything the main use would be as a auto run file to collect error reports from our offic computers

Answer (score 0):

You could do this if you run the program from the USB drive itself, and declare wherever the file is stored as the "working directory" as the USB may have different IDs for different computers...things get messy.

My recommendation is to use File in Java, and Path (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html)

A warning though is that if you copy a directory (folder), the files within that folder are actually not automatically copied...its just the way it works. (more here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html)

Assuming the file is always in the same place going to the same place. For example:

```
Files.copy(source, destination, options);
```

or you can open text file and read from it for a more advanced method:

```
Files.copy(InputStream, path, options);
```

etc.